# Multiple left joins on same table but different rows

Tags: mysql

im want to make multiple joins on the same table but with different aliases:

```
Table1
id
 1
 2

Table2
id pid
 1  1
 2  1
 3  2
 4  2
```

What I tryed

```
SELECT
  t1.id    AS ´t1.id´,
  t2_1.id  AS ´t2_1.id´,
  t2_1.pid AS ´t2_1.pid´,
  t2_2.id, AS ´t2_2.id´,
  t2_2.pid AS ´t2_2.pid´
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_1 ON t2_1.pid = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_2 ON t2_2.pid = t1.id
```

What I'm expecting as result is

```
t1.id = 1, t2_1.id = 1, t2_1.pid = 1, t2_2.id = 2, t2_2.pid = 1
t1.id = 2, t2_1.id = 3, t2_1.pid = 2, t2_2.id = 4, t2_2.pid = 2
```

But im getting the same result on both joins. Is there a way for each join to use the next matching row and not the first? Or do I need to use multiple pid and store them in t1?

Thanks :)

Comment: alter the 3rd join to `LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_2 ON t2_2.pid = t1.id and T2_2.Pid<> T2_1.PID` assuming only 2 IDs for each PID, or you could just add one to

Comment: How should table2 know if it should serve as t2_1 and provide 3, or ar t2_2 and provide 4?

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on my question: How should table2 know if it should serve as t2_1 and provide 3, or ar t2_2 and provide 4?

I think you need to change:

```
Table2
id pid
 1  1
 2  1
 3  2
 4  2
```

to

```
Table2
id pid_1 pid_2
 1  1     1
 2  1     2
 3  2     1
 4  2     2
```

And change the joins accordingly.

Comment: This would work, but in my case i dont know how many rows i'll need in the second table. It depands on which primary table is used in this select. I think what might work is to use the id value of the second table. This value must be higher then the one of the row before. I'll try this later and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As I assumed you can do this:

```
SELECT
  t1.id    AS ´t1.id´,
  t2_1.id  AS ´t2_1.id´,
  t2_1.pid AS ´t2_1.pid´,
  t2_2.id, AS ´t2_2.id´,
  t2_2.pid AS ´t2_2.pid´
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_1 ON t2_1.pid = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_2 ON t2_2.pid = t1.id AND t2_2.id > t2_1.id
```

You have to use `AND t2_2.id > t2_1.id` for every new join making a back-reference to the one before.